# how to know whether a file has changed or not in php

Tags: php, cmd

i have created this small script which can be used to detect whether the file has changed or not. bt unfortunately its not working. Someone Pls help me out.

```
<?php
$l_m1 = filemtime("C:\wamp\www\learning\h.aspx");
print("filemtime1");
print($l_m1);
sleep(10);
$l_m2 = filemtime("C:\wamp\www\learning\h.aspx");
print("filemtime2");
print($l_m2);
if((int)$l_m1 != (int)$l_m2)
{
    alert("the files are different");
    system("start d:/kalimba.mp3");
}
```

Comment: Any output error? What do you mean it is not working? I see l_m1 and l_m2 is directed to a same file.

Comment: i have given sleep(10) so within that time i modify the file. But its not working. the out put m getting is "filemtime11430101042filemtime21430101042" thats it

Comment: in the above comment, though i modify the file, but still the numbers dont change

Comment: m randomly changing the content of the file within the spam of 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the filemtime function results of this function are cached

so you must use clearstatcache() to clears file status cache;

try below:

```
$l_m1 = filemtime("h.php");
print("filemtime1");
print($l_m1);
sleep(10);
clearstatcache();
$l_m2 = filemtime("h.php");
print("filemtime2");
print($l_m2);
if((int)$l_m1 != (int)$l_m2)
{
    alert("the files are different");
    system("start d:/kalimba.mp3");
}
```

Comment: its still the same and nothing has changed.

Comment: are you sure? It works in my normal！  You change your address again Folder folder you？

Comment: the file name is h.aspx and u have mentioned h.php. so is their going to be any difference.?? coz its not working at all

Comment: No! This is something to do with the file type